# how to solve errors while clean and build

Tags: java

i'm facing a long list of error when i click clean and build in order to make jar file 
i also tried to replace this

```
import static com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet.BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets.table;
```

with this

```
import static com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet.BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets.*;
```

can you help me with this thanks in advance

```
E:\Lectures Nd Assimants\2nd semester\Project\RestaurantManagement\src\restaurantmanagement\CounterSale.java:8: error: package com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet does not exist
import static com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet.BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets.*;
E:\Lectures Nd Assimants\2nd semester\Project\RestaurantManagement\src\restaurantmanagement\CounterSale2.java:8: error: package com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet does not exist
import static com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet.BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets.*;
E:\Lectures Nd Assimants\2nd semester\Project\RestaurantManagement\src\restaurantmanagement\Delivery.java:8: error: package com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet does not exist
import static com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet.BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets.*;
E:\Lectures Nd Assimants\2nd semester\Project\RestaurantManagement\src\restaurantmanagement\Delivery2.java:8: error: package com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet does not exist
import static com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet.BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets.*;
E:\Lectures Nd Assimants\2nd semester\Project\RestaurantManagement\src\restaurantmanagement\Sales.java:8: error: package com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet does not exist
import static com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet.BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets.*;
E:\Lectures Nd Assimants\2nd semester\Project\RestaurantManagement\src\restaurantmanagement\deals.java:8: error: package com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet does not exist
import static com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet.BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets.*;
E:\Lectures Nd Assimants\2nd semester\Project\RestaurantManagement\src\restaurantmanagement\staff.java:8: error: package com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet does not exist
import static com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet.BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets.*;
E:\Lectures Nd Assimants\2nd semester\Project\RestaurantManagement\src\restaurantmanagement\user.java:8: error: package com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet does not exist
import static com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet.BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets.*;
Note: E:\Lectures Nd Assimants\2nd semester\Project\RestaurantManagement\src\restaurantmanagement\Login.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
8 errors
E:\Lectures Nd Assimants\2nd semester\Project\RestaurantManagement\nbproject\build-impl.xml:923: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Lectures Nd Assimants\2nd semester\Project\RestaurantManagement\nbproject\build-impl.xml:263: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: these errors are results of either bad configuration, or mistakes in your code. In your case, I think you are missing a dependency

Comment: Which java version are you using? Anyway you shouldn't ever be using [any of the `sun` packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html). The only doc I can find for that class belongs to openjdk and it's an *internal* class for jaxrs, you shouldn't use that one, as you aren't guaranteed that the same class will be available in other JVMs.

Comment: `com.sun.xml.internal` means it's **internal** to the code developed by Sun (previous developer of Java), and that it should **not** be used directly by application code, as it is **undocumented** and likely to change in non-backwards compatible ways in never versions of Java. Just like you've just seen happen to your code. --- Either use the Sun Java version that the code was designed for, or fix the code to not use Sun internal classes.

Comment: Please show your code (see [mcve]). It's extremely unlikely that you intentionally are using XML infoset implementation classes in regular restaurantmanagement code. You probably picked the wrong constant or class name. (Like you were referring to restaurant tables and your IDE auto-completed that to the static public field tables in `BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets`)

Comment: Dependency for com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet is missing.

Comment: Don't use 'import ......*' statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Download the [*fastinfoset-1.2.7.jar*](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/fastinfoset/fastinfoset-1.2.7.jar.zip).
- Add the jar to your project.
- Change your import statement,

  ```
  import com.sun.xml.fastinfoset.alphabet.BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets;
  ```
- Clean and build

Comment: The import needs to be changed too, as that package doesn't exist in the jar.

Comment: @AbdulRahmanMaqbool The real problem is: you should not use this class. You fixed a **symptom**, not the problem.